How to use Set-Cookie headers when use [laravel-sanctum] and [nginx reverse proxy]
I'm making laravel-santum(with vue3) and nginx reverse proxy server on Docker enviroment.
I found something is worg when I send get request "/sanctum/csrf-cookie",
there is no response 'Set-Cookie' header and no way to get headers from backend.
without nginx, everyting goes well.
I can get Set-Cookie header by curl or POSTMAN program,
and my frontend works well too.
I have searched and tried so many things but
cannot know to "/sanctum/csrf-cookie" by 'Set-Cookie' header and
how to send other backend headers through nginx reverse proxy server.
here is my nginx default.conf file ( included in nginx.conf http scope)
default.conf
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
#    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
#}
#
#server {
#    listen 443 ssl;
#    listen [::]:443 ssl;
#
#    ssl_certificate /var/www/.mkcert/cert.pem;
#    ssl_certificate_key /var/www/.mkcert/key.pem;
#    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
#    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
#    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    index index.php index.html;
    server_name _;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    # access_log off;
    root /var/www/public;

    # nginx server version
    server_tokens off;
    
    # allow header
    ignore_invalid_headers off;
    underscores_in_headers on; # when off, get info msg at log

    # add headaer
#    add_header author 'oscar';
#    add_header aristo_1 $uri;


    # frontend http proxy server
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string; # upstream
#        proxy_connect_timeout 3600;
#        proxy_send_timeout 3600;
#        proxy_read_timeout 3600;
#        send_timeout 3600;

    # ~* ignore upscales, "location =" is not a regx
        location ~* /favicons/ {
            return 204;
            access_log     off;
            log_not_found  off;
        }

        # frontend http proxy pass and header settings
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9000; # default localhost
#        proxy_ssl_verify     off;
#        proxy_set_header Upgrade           $http_upgrade;
#        proxy_set_header Connection        "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host              $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
#        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
#        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
#        proxy_set_header Cookie $http_cookie;
#        proxy_set_header X-XSRF-TOKEN $http_x_xsrf_token;
#        proxy_set_header X-TOKEN $http_xsrf_token;
#
    }

    # backend
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =403;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php83:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO         $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param  HTTP_HOST          $host;
        fastcgi_param  HTTP_USER_AGENT    $http_user_agent;
        fastcgi_param  HTTP_ACCEPT        $http_accept;
        fastcgi_param  HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE $http_accept_language;
        fastcgi_param  HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING $http_accept_encoding;
        fastcgi_param  HTTP_COOKIE        $http_cookie;
        fastcgi_param  HTTP_CONNECTION    $http_connection;
        fastcgi_param  HTTP_UPGRADE       $http_upgrade;

#        fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;
#        add_header aristo4_ $uri; # ignore add_header of server scope
#
#        # fastcgi_pass_header Set-Cookie;
#        # fastcgi_pass_header Cookie;
#        # fastcgi_pass_header Authorization;
#        # fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
#
#        add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
#        add_header XSRF-TOKEN $http_xsrf_token;
#        add_header end ____________;
    }

    # deny exceptions
    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}

Https setting is work well when I develop frontend vue3 stuffs.
Without reverse proxy server, (vue3 <-> laravel) everything is done well.
But If I manage revserse proxy server (vue3 <-> nginx <-> laravel),
nothing is returned on my headers from backend server.
I tried so many nginx settings above default.conf file,
but there is no answer for headers pass through nginx proxy server.
So, I've got a conclusion.

maybe the nginx proxy server cannot send backend api server's headers.

I cannot solve this problem by documents and web sources alone.


then, can you help me how to send 'Set-Cookie' header through nginx server?

I've got a answer by myself, there is huge update of over 10 version laravel framework, but some of my codes are in previous laravel 9 version. In common situation, combination of 9 and over 10 version codes works well. But some critical actions not work at all, like header response, etc.
It is totally my fault cannot find real problem of tech stacks, but a little bit feeling unfair of framework.. So hard to know my mistake in the complex of these sources.
